# 403 Forbidden PUT request Nextjs s3

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to upload to my s3 bucket but I keep getting a 403 forbidden error. I've looked into it and based on what I found I made sure my bucket policy was correct:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicListGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As well as my credentials. Regardless, the error persists, any ideas?

Here's my logic that successful gets the presigned url but fails at the put request:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const uploadPhoto = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target.files?.[0]!;
    const filename = file.name;
    const fileType = file.type;

    console.log("filename", filename, fileType);

    var credentials = {
      accessKeyId: my_key,
      secretAccessKey: my_secret,
    };
    AWS.config.update({ credentials: credentials, region: "us-east-1" });
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var presignedGETURL = s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
      Bucket: my_bucket,
      Key: filename, //filename
      Expires: 100, //time to expire in seconds
    });

    // const res = await fetch(`/api/s3?file=${filename}&fileType=${fileType}`);
    // const { url } = await res.json();

    console.log(presignedGETURL);

    const upload = await fetch(presignedGETURL, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: file,
      headers: { "Content-Type": fileType },
    });

    if (upload.ok) {
      console.log("Uploaded successfully!");
    } else {
      console.error("Upload failed.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={uploadPhoto} />
  );
};

export default ImageUpload;
```

Comment: Look very closely at the operation name you're passing to `getSignedUrl()`. Do you think that perhaps `getObject` should not be used for uploading?